# Implement "tee" without leaving kernel space

Tags: c, windows, splice, tee

In Linux, the `tee` command copies data from stdin to both stdout and a file; one could implement this function without the data ever leaving kernel space by leveraging the `tee` and `splice` system calls.  What functions are necessary to implement the `tee` command on Windows without the data ever leaving kernel space?

While the `tee` command has a trivial implementation with `read`, `open`, and `write` that copies data in user space, I'm specifically interested in learning how to split a file stream without data leaving kernel space.

Comment: I think you have 'Unix' and 'Linux' confused.  The [`tee(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tee) and [`splice(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) system calls are specific to Linux and are not available on other Unix variants.  For instance, Mac OS X has neither `tee` nor `splice` in either section 2 or section 3 (system calls or library functions) of the manual.  You implement `tee` (the command) with the usual `read`, `write`, `open`, `close` system calls; there's nothing very fancy about it.  Those, or their direct analogues, would work on Windows just fine.

Comment: OK I updated my question based on your comment.  I only mentioned the command because it's an illustrative example of the system calls.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of this question is faulty. The `tee` command does not depend on the `tee()` or `splice()` system calls, and is not zero-copy; it is essentially implemented as:

```
open file for writing;
while (read some data from stdin) {
    write the data to stdout;
    write the data to the file;
}
```

The only system calls involved are `open()`, `read()`, and `write()`, and the Windows versions of these calls are essentially identical to the UNIX versions.

Comment: I just updated my question for clarity.  This question is specifically about transferring knowledge of Linux system calls to Windows.  The command itself is only used for ease of discussion.

Comment: Then you need to give an example of how you intend to use those calls. The `tee` command doesn't (and cannot) use them, and the equivalent Windows calls are likely to depend on the exact application of `tee` and `splice`. (That is, there won't be a 1:1 mapping.)

Comment: Why can't the `tee` command couldn't be implemented with the `tee` function--it splits stdin to stdout and a file[s]?  I just want to split a file descriptor without leaving kernel space.

Comment: `tee()` and `splice()` have some unusual restrictions that make them unsuitable for use in the `tee` command. (Specifically, at least one of the FDs must be a pipe.)

Answer (score 1):

No such functionality is built into Windows, but it should be possible in principle to write a tee-like kernel-mode device driver.  Of course, it would still work *basically* the same way as the user-mode implementation: receive the data from the source, write it to the destinations.  You would be able to receive the data as output sent to the tee device, rather than issuing read operations, which is a bit more efficient, and you'd avoid a few user/kernel-mode transitions, but even so I'm unsure how much of a performance improvement you'd get.

My guess is that it probably wouldn't be worth the effort involved, but perhaps there are edge cases.

I'm also not sure whether or not a kernel driver could deal with console I/O in older versions of Windows, as that uses psuedo-handles rather than real handles.  But console I/O is slow, so if any of your endpoints is a console you may as well stick to the user-mode implementation anyway - that definitely won't be a bottleneck in this scenario.

A splice-like kernel-mode device driver should also be possible.  This one would probably be implemented in exactly the same way as the user-mode version, albeit with a slightly different API.

In either case, using a kernel-mode driver would likely make it easier to efficiently handle lots of simultaneous tees and/or splices from different processes.  In user-mode you'd likely wind up with a separate thread, or even a separate process, for each one.

Comment: Thanks.  What functions/API should I research to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd probably want to start with [Getting started with Windows drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554690(v=vs.85).aspx).  I imagine you'd just use ZwWriteFile to forward the data on to the destinations, you should be able to call that from DispatchWrite if the handles are open in the context of the source application.  If you have to get the handles from a different application, ZwDuplicateObject should help; you'd probably want the OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE option.  (Disclaimer: I've done some Windows kernel-mode programming, but I'm not an expert.)